Set cursor when drag and drop out of browser onto desktop
I am looking to implement dragging a div outside the browser window and it creating a new window with the div in it.
Whilst my code probably isn't perfect, I can do that with this:


let dragged = null;
let dropTarget = null;

document.addEventListener("dragstart", e => dragged = e.target);
document.addEventListener("dragend", e => {
  if (dropTarget == null) {
    const w = window.open("", "_blank", `height=200,width=200,left=${e.screenX},top=${e.screenY},toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0`);
    w.document.body.appendChild(dragged);
  }
});

document.addEventListener("dragenter", e => dropTarget = e.target);
document.addEventListener("dragleave", e => {
  if (dropTarget == e.target) {
    dropTarget = null;
  }
});
<div draggable="true">Draggable div</div>
 



IMPORTANT NOTE: This example does not work as advertised, you need to copy the code in a HTML file and use that.
When dragging outside the window onto the desktop, the cursor icon is not-allowed.
If there is anyway I can trick the browser into thinking the drop is allowed (with a better icon) without actually performing a drop, but instead opening the new window?

Please test your code before publishing, there were 2 syntax errors in it. I'm not sure it is correct now, can you check?

@KIKOSoftware - done, thanks.

Anyway, which OS are you using? I'm on Windows 11 using Firefox or Chrome and when I am dragging the DIV outside the window onto the desktop nothing happens. Chrome does report an error, Firefox does not. I also have a feeling that it is the responsibility of the receiving dragging area to choose a cursor icon.

@KIKOSoftware - Chrome on Windows 10. It doesn't work via the JSBIN (or whatever inline mechanism is used on SO) for me either. I have to copy it to an html file and open that to use it (presumably perms around window.open). I think you are right about the responsibility of the receiving area...I was hoping there was a way I could hack it (perhaps by switching out the transfer object?)

Yes, when I create a normal HTML file, it does work in Chrome. In Firefox I need to confirm opening a popup window, which is what you're actually doing. I don't know how to change the cursor. You basically cannot drop on the desktop, hence that block cursor, and you use a trick to get around that. But not knowing doesn't mean it is impossible....
